# How to deny access to a specific view with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to deny access to the admin site of a webpage created with CodeIgniter.

This is the link
www.mydomain.com/**admin**

I created an **htaccess** file with following code

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I put the htaccess file in **application/view/admin**

Obviously it does not work.
What is the correct way to deny a specific folder in a CodeIgniter project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Why not just add the ip check in the `Admin` class constructor?

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if ($this->input->ip_address() != 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
    {
        show_404();
    }    
}
```